# Android fullscreen AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

I'm trying to make a full screen dialog in my Android application, but I'm not able to expand it to the status bar. You can see the gray status bar in the image below.

**EDIT 1:**
It seems to be a problem related to the operating system installed and not to the Android components, because I'm experiencing this problem only on certain devices.

[image]

AlertDialog creation:

```
    val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.FullscreenDialogStyle)
    val binding = DialogSuccessBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    binding.SuccessDialogMessage.text = getString(R.string.AddGuestCard_Success)
    builder.setView(binding.root)
    builder.background = ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.primary))
    builder.setBackgroundInsetBottom(0)
    builder.setBackgroundInsetTop(0)
    builder.setBackgroundInsetStart(0)
    builder.setBackgroundInsetEnd(0)
    builder.show()
```

AlertDialog style:

```
<style name="FullscreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Which kind of devices? Those have camera notches on the gray area?

Comment: I have tried only on Oneplus 6, and yes, it has camera notch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yes, it has camera notch

To make your dialog a full screen by covering the camera notch area (cutout display area), you need to explicitly adjust the display cutout to `shortEdges` or `always` using `android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode` attribute in the dialog theme:

```
<style name="FullscreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ....
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>
```

Please [check documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout) here for further research;.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.FullscreenDialogStyle)

            val binding = DialogSuccessBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            binding.SuccessDialogMessage.text = getString(R.string.AddGuestCard_Success)
            builder.setView(binding.root)
            builder.background = ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.primary))
            builder.setBackgroundInsetBottom(0)
            builder.setBackgroundInsetTop(0)
            builder.setBackgroundInsetStart(0)
            builder.setBackgroundInsetEnd(0)
           var dialog= builder.show()
            dialog.window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

Comment: Same result as before